# how i can execute what my code by condition with selenium?

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i want execute my code by condition

my selenium's code is find element at website after connect site, and in case found it execute first code or in case not found element, second code execute. that is i want it

but i run execute my code, i got a error what like below code

```
[2019-06-12 19:11:45] local.ERROR: Undefined property: 
App\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::$WebDriverExpectedCondition 
{"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property:
```

and below code is my laravel code

```
if($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="err_common"]/p'))){
    Log::info('fail login');
} else {
    Log::info('success login');
}
```

How can I fix it to what I want?
my english level is very low,,,,
thanks for watching my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$driver->findElement(...)` method call should throw a NoSuchElementException if that element does not exist. You should be able to wrap your code in a try-catch block instead of an if-statement:

```php
try {
    $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="err_common"]/p'));

    Log::info('success login');
} catch (NoSuchElementException $ex)
    Log::info('fail login');
}
```